# ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (E:\Anaconda\envs\nlp\Lib\collections\__init__.py)

Tags: collections, mapping, importerror, gensim, iterable

I was getting this error while importing gensim. I was also getting this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (E:\Anaconda\envs\nlp\Lib\collections_*init*_.py)

I tried this and it absolutely worked fine.

https://youtu.be/qV1VXka_N7M